# PHP move_uploaded_file doesn't work

Tags: php, android, http, http-post

I'm using HTTP post to upload image to server and I have the following PHP code:

```
$base_path = "";
$target_path = $base_path . basename ( $_FILES ['uploadfile'] ['name'] );
if (move_uploaded_file ( $_FILES ['uploadfile'] ['tmp_name'], $target_path )) {
    echo "Good";
} else {
    echo "FAIL";
}
```

I'm sure the image has been uploaded to temp. But no matter what, I just can't store image file. my current permission is 664 for testing.

Comment: Check permission for the apache user and check the file path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your `$base_path` variable to an absolute path to where you are storing the file. ( ie. `/path/to/your/document/root/image/directory/` )

Additionally, make sure the directory you will be storing the images in is either owned by the apache user or that it is writable by the apache user (chmod 777).

Comment: i set permission to 777 and base path to "/var/www/myapp/" but it still return FIAL to me is there any other setting that limits my write permission?  return : ["name":"test.jpg","type":"","tnp_name":"\/tmp\/phpqG2wsn.","error":0,"size":47762] filepath: /var/www/myapp/test.jpg stat: FAIL

Comment: I changed the path to dirname(__FILE__) somehow it works thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Pl check the uploaded path is correct before move the file

&&

Set the folder permission to 777 where you upload the file.
```

Thanks!